# Breaking verse across multiple pages

Tags: page-breaking, verse

I am using

```
\begin{verse}
.....
\end{verse}
```

and I have a problem splitting it across pages. The `verse` environment is leaving half a page blank. How can I spread verse across multiple pages. I learned that for tables we use `longtable`,  is there such a thing for `verse` as well?

Here is the edited message

```
Lt. Tara came back in a trice fetching that litter of the dead, getting it carried by gritty and suitable
Vanara-s. [4-25-21]


\begin{verse}      
दिव्याम् भद्र आसन युताम् शिबिकाम् स्यंदन उपमम् |           \\
 पक्षि कर्मभिः आचित्राम् द्रुम कर्म विभूषिताम् || ४-२५-२२           \\

 अचिताम् चित्र पत्तीभिः सुनिविष्टाम् समंततः |           \\
 विमानम् इव सिद्धानाम् जाल वात आयान आयुताम् || ४-२५-२३           \\

 सुनियुक्तानाम् विशालाम् च सुकृताम् शिल्पिभिः कृतात् |           \\
 दारु पर्वतकोपेताम् चारु कर्म परिष्कृताम् || ४-२५-२४           \\

 वर आभरण हारैः च चित्र माल्य उपशोभिताम् |           \\
 गुहागहन संच्छन्नाम् रक्त चन्दन भूषिताम् || ४-२५-२५           \\

 पुष्प ओघैः समभिच्छन्नाम् पद्म मालाभिः एव च |           \\
 तरुण आदित्य वर्णाभिः भ्राजमानभिः आवृताम् || ४-२५-२६
  \end{verse}
```

Comment: I did a quick test, and the contents of my `verse` environment split nicely across pages. Therefore, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I am using begin/end verse. I am attaching the output to show the blank page its leaving. https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeMzhiYzZiYjktMGU2OS00MDNmLWEwMjktZDRiYTI5ZDY4OTQ5&hl=en_US let me know if this helps

Comment: Don't show the output -- show the input.

Comment: @lockstep I edited the orignal message, since there is not much to say because its just begin{verse} ... end{verse}, its part of a big document.

Comment: Please see the link that lockstep is referring to. We need a [compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: If I add a suitable preamble for XeLaTeX, the poem splits nicely across pages.

Comment: @Aku We need to see the full preamble, as there might be some package causing the problem.

Comment: Here are the files. The error appears on Page 8. verse starts on page 9 leaving half a page blank.  https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeODIzZjFhZmYtZTRjZS00YjM3LWE5NGUtYzM0OTc0OGEwOWY5&hl=en_US     https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeNjU1NDMyZjAtYmE4ZC00MWMxLWEzNzAtYTBiZjAzZGM1YzA0&hl=en_US

Comment: @Aku: The files you provided do not compile for me. You need to produce [a **minimal** **working** example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  Take your existing file and reduce it down until it still produces the problem, and everything that can be removed has been removed.  Often this will help you solve your own problem (has worked for me many times).

Comment: I removed everything and complied before uploading.  It compilied for me. It uses Sanskrit 2003. Other than this I don't know how else I can provide minimal example here. Sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examining your input, it's clear that you *aren't* using the `verse` environment, but a `Verse` environment that you're defining yourself and that uses features from the **varwidth** package thus building an indivisible unit.

You can modify the definition of this environment as

```
\newenvironment{Verse}
  {\singlespacing\longtable{@{}c@{}}}
  {\endlongtable}
```

Blank lines in the input will not leave an empty line, but it will be sufficient to add a `\\` instead. A better way would be to use `\stopstanza` to end a stanza, where the command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\stopstanza}{\\[\normalbaselineskip]}
```

In order to avoid a page break between verses, use `\\*`.

```
Lt. Tara came back in a trice fetching that litter of the dead, getting it carried by gritty and suitable
Vanara-s. [4-25-21]


\begin{Verse}      
दिव्याम् भद्र आसन युताम् शिबिकाम् स्यंदन उपमम् |           \\
 पक्षि कर्मभिः आचित्राम् द्रुम कर्म विभूषिताम् || ४-२५-२२           \stopstanza

 अचिताम् चित्र पत्तीभिः सुनिविष्टाम् समंततः |           \\
 विमानम् इव सिद्धानाम् जाल वात आयान आयुताम् || ४-२५-२३           \stopstanza

 सुनियुक्तानाम् विशालाम् च सुकृताम् शिल्पिभिः कृतात् |           \\
 दारु पर्वतकोपेताम् चारु कर्म परिष्कृताम् || ४-२५-२४           \stopstanza

 वर आभरण हारैः च चित्र माल्य उपशोभिताम् |           \\
 गुहागहन संच्छन्नाम् रक्त चन्दन भूषिताम् || ४-२५-२५           \stopstanza

 पुष्प ओघैः समभिच्छन्नाम् पद्म मालाभिः एव च |           \\
 तरुण आदित्य वर्णाभिः भ्राजमानभिः आवृताम् || ४-२५-२६
 \end{Verse}
```

Comment: My requirement was to have the verse at the enter but left justified. Verse environment did not do the center. I could not do that and asked here and got the answer to define verse environment and it worked but later it gave this problem of starting from new page. I am new to TeX writing. I am working with a document which has 24k verses.

Comment: Here is the difference in the output since I can not attach the output image here, I uploaded to my google docs  Here is the link https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeNmNkZGY1ZjYtOTIzMC00ZWE3LWIyMmMtMzQ1NmUzZDM5ZWQ1&hl=en_US

Comment: @Aku Don't use a blank line to separate stanzas, but `\stopstanza` instead of ``\\``.